# how to show gnuplot timeseries graph from log of changes

Tags: gnuplot

I have an application that produce log like that:

```
14:48:16, 41.0
14:50:01, 40.0
14:54:01, 41.0
14:54:04, 40.0
14:55:10, 41.0
14:55:22, 40.0
15:00:13, 41.0
...
```

It is current time and the measured temperature. The application writes a line to the log file when temperature changes.

I want plot a temperature graph via gnuplot and I tried that:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set yrange [30:50]
set xrange ["14:40":"16:50"]
plot 'temp.csv' using 1:2 with lines
```

It shows a graph like that:

[image: graph]

But I want the lines are horizontal and form a step at time when the temperature changes. The result should look like the blue line:

[image: desired graph]

How can I force gnuplot to do that? I can do that vi the log preprocessing but I want to do that only via gnuplot only if possible.

Comment: replace `with lines` by `with steps`.

Comment: Ouch, that is so easy. I was blind when I tried to find it. Thanks.

Comment: @ZabojCampula: Post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnuplot has bunch of styles that can be used for displaying data. The `with lines` option connects each data point with lines. It is suitable to smoothly varying data.

Data containing the time and value that is valid since this time till next change is can be plot as a histogram. Gnuplot plots a histogram if the option `with steps` is specified. So the complete command is

```
plot 'temp.csv' using 1:2 with steps
```

Nice documentation and examples are at http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/intro/style-e.html.